# Replace in SQL substring issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, replace

I would like to replace the all digits in a number with `*`, other than the last 4.

Here is my table:

```
Person
-----------
PersonID PersonBadgeNumber numeric(16,0)
```

Comment: Please post some example data, and before/after example, and correct grammar mistakes in question.  (Clarify what "replace the all digits" means.)  ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method is to use `STUFF()`:

```
DECLARE @n numeric (16, 0);
SET @n = 1234567890123456;
SELECT STUFF(@n, 1, LEN(@n) - 4, REPLICATE('*', LEN(@n) - 4))
```

The above returns:

```
---------------- 
************3456
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work...

```
DECLARE @badgeId Numeric(16, 0) = 1238985495;
SELECT
  REPLICATE('*', LEN(@badgeId) - 4) +
  RIGHT(@badgeId, 4);
-- Produces: ******5495
```

To use it in a query do this:

```
SELECT
  REPLICATE('*', LEN(PersonBadgeNumber) - 4) +
  RIGHT(PersonBadgeNumber, 4) RedactedBadgeNumber
FROM Person;
```